# How to edit video frames without extracting each frame first ? OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am currently extracting frames from a video so I can add some bounding boxes in each frame. Then, I want to put all the frames together and make a new video, using openCV. The problem is that every time I want to do that, I have to extract thousand of frames first. Is there a way to do it without having to extract the frames?
Thanks

Comment: post your current solution code

Comment: My code is much more than this... has a lot of stuff and becomes difficult to understand. I don't want you to correct my code... just want to know if there is a better way of doing this without having to extract the frames first and then put them together to make a video again

Comment: [mre] is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That assumption isn't correct. You can use OpenCV's `VideoCapture` to load a video, get a frame, do some processing on it and save it using a `VideoWriter` object - one frame at a time. There is no need to load all frames into memory and then store them all at once.

Comment: so, instead od cv2.imwrite, I can make cv2.VideoWriter(...).write() ?

Comment: `cv2.imwrite` just saves images, not a video. But yes, you can iteratively add frames using `cv2.VideoWriter().write()`